# Awk: extract different columns from many different files

Tags: file, awk

**File Example**

```
I have a 3-10 amount of files with:

 - different number of columns
 - same number of rows
 - inconsistent spacing (sometimes one space, other tabs, sometimes many spaces) **within** the very files like the below


>      0    55.4      9.556E+09   33
>      1     1.3      5.345E+03    1
>        ........
>     33   134.4      5.345E+04  932
>
       ........
```

I need to get column (say) 1 from file1, column 3 from file2, column 7 from file3 and column 1 from file4 and combine them into a single file, side by side.

**Trial 1:** not working

> ```
> paste <(cut -d[see below] -f1 file1) <(cut -d[see below] -f3 file2) [...]
> ```
>
> where the delimiter was ' ' or empty.

**Trial 2:** working with 2 files but not with many files

> ```
> awk '{
>      a1=$1;b1=$4;
>      getline <"D2/file1.txt";
>      print a1,$1,b1,$4
> }' D1/file1.txt >D3/file1.txt
> ```

Now more general question:

> **How can I extract different columns from many different files?**

Comment: How does using `cut` and `paste` not work?

Comment: I think it's because cut assumes the spacing is constant. I have data formatted with different spacings, in order to have numbers justified to the left of each column. If a number has more digits, there will be less spaces to its left.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

In your `paste` / `cut` attempt, replace `cut` by `awk`:

```
$ paste <(awk '{print $1}' file1 ) <(awk '{print $3}' file2 ) <(awk '{print $7}' file3) <(awk '{print $1}' file4)
```

Comment: paste <(awk '{print $1}' file1 ) <(awk '{print $3}' file2 ) <(awk '{print $7}' file3) <(awk '{print $1}' file4)

Comment: This is **exactly** what I needed, fast and easy. Cheers!

Comment: Is it possible to generalise this for an arbitrary number of input files (e.g. from a for loop)?

Answer (score 8):

Assuming each of your files has the same number of rows, here's one way using `GNU awk`. Run like:

```
awk -f script.awk file1.txt file2.txt file3.txt file4.txt
```

Contents of `script.awk`:

```
FILENAME == ARGV[1] { one[FNR]=$1 }
FILENAME == ARGV[2] { two[FNR]=$3 }
FILENAME == ARGV[3] { three[FNR]=$7 }
FILENAME == ARGV[4] { four[FNR]=$1 }

END {
    for (i=1; i<=length(one); i++) {
        print one[i], two[i], three[i], four[i]
    }
}
```

Note:

By default, `awk` separates columns on whitespace. This includes tab characters and spaces, and any amount of these. This makes `awk` ideal for files with inconsistent spacing. You can also expand the above code to include more files if you wish.

Comment: +1 genuine answer to the title. Probably best answer to my question [here](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18602414/how-to-read-many-input-files-in-awk) also.

Answer (score 1):

The combination of `cut` and `paste` should work:

```
$ cat f1
foo
bar
baz
$ cat f2
1 2 3
4 5 6
7 8 9
$ cat f3
a b c d
e f g h
i j k l
$ paste -d' ' <(cut -f1 f1) <(cut -d' ' -f2 f2) <(cut -d' ' -f3 f3)
foo 2 c
bar 5 g
baz 8 k
```

**Edit:** This works with tabs, too:

```
$ cat f4
a       b       c       d
e       f       g       h
i       j       k       l
$ paste -d' ' <(cut -f1 f1) <(cut -d' ' -f2 f2) <(cut -f3 f4)   
foo 2 c
bar 5 g
baz 8 k
```

Comment: The example works, but only for consistent spacing... There's ambiguity in my question, sorry. I meant inconsistent spacing within the file itself.