# How to read many input files in AWK?

Tags: file, input, awk

I try to understand how to read many input files in AWK with this puzzle **"How can I print 1st column from file 1 and 2nd column from file 2?**

**Input**

```
$ cat test1 
1   4
2   5
3   6
$ cat test2
a   b
c   d   
e   f
```

**Goal**

```
$ awk **ANSWER**
1   b
2   d
3   f
```

Comment: I think this answer [here](http://stackoverflow.com/a/12747866/164148) is by far the closest to this question -- not all points there address this question yet.

Comment: Downvoters should express their concerns so threads could be improved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
awk 'NR==FNR{a[NR]=$1;next} {print a[FNR], $2}' file1 file2
```

Comment: Thank you, clear and succint -- love it! +1

Answer (score 3):

Ed's solution is good, but since `awk` generally exists in an ecosystem, it is good to use other available tools:

```
paste test[12] | awk '{print $1, $4}'
```

This should scale to larger files, since a reasonable implementation of `paste` will not read all of `test1` into memory before producing any output.  (This is not likely to be an actual problem, but is aesthetically pleasing.)

Comment: And easy to remember, good alternative +1!