# sum columns from different files with delimeter

Tags: python, bash, awk

I have a similar problem as described here [Awk: extract different columns from many different files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745834/awk-extract-different-columns-from-many-different-files), but in my case I have many files as input (can be 40, can be 500) and each one is following a latex formatting like

```
 #description & value1 & value2
    cut1 & XXX & YYY & ZZZ
    cut2>B & QQQ & TTT & GGG
```

So, I want to sum up all values under the same column number for the different input files, so in the end I get a new file like

```
cut1 & SUM_XXX & SUM_YYY & SUM_ZZZ
cu2>B & SUM_QQQ & SUM_TTT & SUM_GGG
```

Also, the values can be in scientific format.. I would like to do this either in bash or python. Thanks in advance!

Comment: You might find the python [`csv` module](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/csv.html) helpful.

Comment: What you need is 1) read a file; 2) split a line (string) using the character '&'; 3) sum up the values. You can either use the csv module in python, or just do it yourself using the built-ins. Either way, I think  you will struggle less with python, so try it out an let us know how it goes.

Comment: Just post some sample input and output so we stand chance of coming up with the right answer...

Answer (score 0):

awk to the rescue!

If you have only three columns to aggregate this will do

```
$ awk 'BEGIN{FS=OFS="&"}
            {k=$1;a[k]+=$2;b[k]+=$3;c[k]+=$4} 
         END{for(i in a) print i,a[i],b[i],c[i]}' files*
```