# Print columns from two files

Tags: awk

How to print columns from various files?
I tried according to [Awk: extract different columns from many different files](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12745834/awk-extract-different-columns-from-many-different-files/12747866#12747866)

```
paste <(awk '{printf "%.4f   %.5f ", $1, $2}' FILE.R ) <(awk '{printf "%.6f      %.0f.\n", $3, $4}' FILE_R )

FILE.R == ARGV[1] { one[FNR]=$1 }
FILE.R == ARGV[2] { two[FNR]=$2 }
FILE_R == ARGV[3] { three[FNR]=$3 }
FILE_R == ARGV[4] { four[FNR]=$4 }

END {
    for (i=1; i<=length(one); i++) {
        print one[i], two[i], three[i], four[i]
    }
}
```

but I don't understand how to use this script.

FILE.R

```
56604.6017    2.3893    2.2926    2.2033
56605.1562    2.3138    2.2172    2.2033
```

FILE_R

```
56604.6017   2.29259 0.006699      42.
56605.1562   2.21716 0.007504      40.
```

Output desired

```
56604.6017    2.3893 0.006699      42.
56605.1562    2.3138 0.007504      40.
```

Thank you

Answer (score 4, accepted):

This is one way:

```
$ awk -v OFS="\t" 'NR==FNR{a[$1]=$2;next}{print $1,a[$1],$3,$4}' file1 file2
```

Output:

```
56604.6017      2.3893  0.006699        42.
56605.1562      2.3138  0.007504        40.
```

Explained:

```
$ awk -v OFS="\t" '       # setting the field separator to a tab
NR==FNR {                 # process the first file
    a[$1]=$2              # hash the second field, use first as key
    next
} 
{
    print $1,a[$1],$3,$4  # output 
}' file1 file2
```

If the field spacing with tabs is not enough, use `printf` with modifiers like in your sample.

Comment: Thank you very much

Comment: `{print $1,a[$1],$3,$4}` = `{$2=a[$1]}1`

Comment: @EdMorton Good thinking. (or like I first typoed it, _thingking_ :)